# how to 'go get' files in a different branch in github repo other than master

Tags: go

I need to `go get` following files from [this repo](https://github.com/mattes/migrate)

```
go get github.com/mattes/migrate/driver/mysql
```

but those files are in a different branch, not in `master`. How can I `go get` those files? I tried following way but it didn't get those files that I need.

```
go get gopkg.in/mattes/migrate.v1
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by `go get`, you need to download the files manually to your `GOPATH` or to your `vendor/` folder.

A vendor solution:

```
git clone git@github.com:mattes/migrate.git
    vendor/github.com/mattes/migrate;
cd vendor/github.com/mattes/migrate;
git checkout BRANCH_NAME;
```